# How to Replace bullet points in List with icons in Ionic 2?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, angular2-template, angular2-services

Want to Replace bullet points in List with icons from [Ionicons](https://ionicframework.com/docs/ionicons/) in Ionic 2?

```
<section>
      <ul class="my-nav">
              <li>
                    List Item 1
              </li>
               <li>
                    List Item 2
               </li>
               <li>
                    List Item 3
               </li>
               <li>
                    List Item 4
               </li>
      </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ion-icon` as shown below

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-icon name="leaf" item-start></ion-icon>
      Herbology
    <ion-icon name="rose" item-end></ion-icon>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```